# Private key does not persist even with X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, wcf

I have been searching for quite a while now but i am unable to find the answer to the following. I am storing a key pair in Windows Store, and recently started receiving the "Keyset does not exist" error. Investigating a bit further i found out it could be two things, 1 - The private key is not stored with the persist key set attribute (X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet) and 2 - access rights to the key. I have tried both 1 and 2 with no success on one machine (in my machine it works apparently). The strange thing is that when i look into Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys (and S-1-5-18) the key remains there but only for a period of time then it is deleted which means that it is not persisting.

```
//If decoded then save as RSACryptoServiceProvider
newCert.PrivateKey = DecodePrivateKey(privateKeyFile, pkPassword)
```

if (newCert.PrivateKey == null)
throw new System.NullReferenceException("Decoded private key resulted in a null reference. Unable to store certificate.");

byte[] pfx = newCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx);
newCert = new X509Certificate2(pfx, string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

I am running this code on a WCF Service hosted on IIS, and the certificate is deleted even if i give permissions to Network Service, the AppPoolIdentity, my account, etc through MMC-CertMgr. Would anyone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I have just found out today that since i am doing this through a WCF service, the application pool is deleting the private key when it reaches its idle time limit so i am completely sure that it is the application pool the one disposing of the private key which causes the key to be deleted from the Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys and S-1-5-18 folders. Today i left a test running where i disabled Idle time shut down from the application pool bu i am still not sure if the private key will stop persisting with a restart or something like that?

Would anybody know how to make the application pool stop deleting my private keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best answer, but if anyone needs to know the way i worked around this back then was to set the AppPoolIdentity to an Administrator account and set the "Idle Time-out (minutes)" value in IIS to 0. Only this way the AppPool will not delete the certificate files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for this particular case, but at work we have had problems using the RSACryptoServiceProvider in a Web Application context as well.

What fixed the problem for us was that we set "Load User Profile" on the corresponding ApplicationPool to "true". In our case we actually got PermissionDenied errors though, so not sure it will work for you.